# Blender Particles

Tags: particles

In this link

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/vertex_groups.html

It is written

Length
    Defines the “length” of the particle distribution.

What does this writing mean?

Comment: Please make a title that reflects the content of the question, not something vague.

Answer (score 1):

It effects the hair length:

[image]

It takes the length of hair particles (edited with Particle comb brush) as input and multiplies it by the weights.

Only the Density vertex group affects Emitter type particles. Length and the rest are for shaping and rendering hairs

Comment: A Particle System can either be of type Emitter or Hair.  Are you stating that [Length] has zero or nonzero effect on the type [Emitter]?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger yes, only the density input effects Emitter type particles, the rest is for shaping and rendering hairs.

Comment: I suggest the proposed answer be updated with your comment information.